# Why did error not trigger when println was run?

Tags: rust

I was trying to trace the error in my Rust API code. When I ran it, it showed the following in the terminal:

```
Server running on localhost:3000
auth
auth err1
...
```

Notice `auth err1` was printed from inside `.ok_or()` in my code below, but the `StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST` was not triggered as I got `200 OK` back. Why? What happened?

```rust
pub async fn auth<T>(mut request: Request<T>, next: Next<T>) -> Result<Response, StatusCode> {
    println!("auth");
    let token = request
        .headers()
        .typed_get::<Authorization<Bearer>>()
        .ok_or({
            println!("auth err1");
            StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST
        })?
        .token()
        .to_owned();
    //other code to connect to DB and retrieve user data...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you put `println!("auth err1")` in a block it will immediately be executed no matter if `typed_get` returned `Some` or `None`.
You need to make it a closure and use `ok_or_else` to only print in the `None` case:

```rust
    .ok_or_else(|| {
        println!("auth err1");
        StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST
    })?
```